# Postman: how can I get a value from url of get-request in post request (/oauth2)?

Tags: api, testing, oauth-2.0, postman

I send a post-request by Postman. I have received answers, which consists of post and get requests in Console:

```
Exmpl:
post-reguest https://domain/oauth2?response_type=token
get-request https: //domain/Result?response_type=token&&result=success#access_token=some_token
```

I'd like to get the value "some_token" from get-request and put it in variable of Environment in Test (Postman).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i understand the question. But you can use the Token that you get like so: [Choose the type of Authentication (for example Bearer Token) and insert the Token in the field below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz3DN.png)

Comment: Thank you so much! I think, I can use it!